# When a company decides to issue more shares in a secondary offering, how is the price determined?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-valuation

Suppose there is a market price of shares, say $1 per share. The company decides to issue more shares. At what price should they be sold? And who determines the price? The company itself or the market?

I am not asking about IPO. Rather, imagine the company has already been public for a year, and then it issues more shares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At what price should they be sold? And who determines the price?

It's very similar to an IPO. The *market* (meaning the people that buy the shares) determines the price. There will typically be an *underwriter* in the middle that will agree to buy the shares for a specific price (based on what they *think* the market will pay for them), then facilitate the sale of those shares on the open market, hoping to make a profit overall. The market may be willing to pay more or less than the existing shares, depending on what the company plans to *do* with the proceeds.

Comment: A typical dilutive secondary offering can resemble an IPO.  The issue is priced by the  underwriter(s) and shares are offered at that price to the account holders at syndicate firms.

Comment: Can the company sell these stocks partly, say, 10% per day in order to see market sentiment and based on this correct the price?